# Using regular expressions in Spring bean value

Tags: java, spring

I have spring bean with takes a ftp server url with username and password.

```
<bean id="ftp" class="com....XYZ">
   <property name="url" value=""> /
</bean>
```

The value has 3 parts, ftpusername, ftpserver and ftp password. I want to get ftpusername and ftpserver from properties files and ${ftpUsername} then add a special character say '#' and then appended the server ${ftpServer} and then appened "&" and then append password by taking the password from a different bean below

```
<bean id="ftpPass">
<property name="pass" value="com...LMNPassword.getPassword()"
</bean>
```

how can i set the value of property url in bean ftp above to                `value= "${ftpUSername}+'#'+ ${ftpServer} + '&' + ftpPass"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Expression Language. But properties from property file are not accessible from expression directly so additional beans are required

```
<bean id="ftpPass" >
    <property name="pass" value="com...LMNPassword.getPassword()"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ftpUsername" class="java.lang.String" >
    <constructor-arg value="${ftpUsername}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ftpServer" class="java.lang.String" >
    <constructor-arg value="${ftpServer}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ftp">
    <property name="url" value="#{ftpUsername + '#' + ftpServer + '&amp;' + ftpPass.pass}" />
</bean>
```

Another option is to set plain values into ftp bean and construct url in init method

Comment: Thank you!! I am trying to get password from another object below.                                                                    
 class SSS{                                                                      
  public string getPassword()                                                
 { return "abdjejdb"}     }                           and in XML I am doing this.         <bean id="ftpPass" >
    <property name="#{new SSS().getPassword()"/>
</bean>
 And trying to access it in bean "ftp" above , but its failing with error Type cant be found 'SSS' failed to resolve constructor

Comment: @uideveloperui - use fully qualified class name in expression, i.e. `<property name="#{new com.my.package...SSS().getPassword()"/>` or define bean of SSS class then you'll be able to use this bean in expression